# How to handle download dialogs on mobile devices with Appium

Tags: selenium, appium

I am using Selenium with Appium and my problem is "**when i click on a download button it shows path to save the file**." This is a mobile OS control, how do I interact with Mobile Controls?

Are there any tools like Sikuli or AutoIt (windows handling) for Android and iOS devices. Since this is how I would interact with it on a desktop.

Comment: question title does not match with actual question. update your question to ask a solution for actual issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to download a file using Selenium's WebDriver?](http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2197/how-to-download-a-file-using-seleniums-webdriver)

Comment: @bish please read the question clearly i mentioned platform as Mobile not Desktop.

Comment: @TestingWithArif  question upgraded please provide solution.

Comment: Are you automating a browser-based application or a native application? As far as I know Appium is capable of automating native applications and the action you want to perform is also a native one so there should not be a need of any other tools. I would advise looking into appium groups for the solution.

Comment: @TestingWithArif hi appium supports Hybrid app, so i want to handle mobile download dialogs, i thin k you are much clear about this

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand your problem or not but let me try.
in your application any pop-up come you no need to use the **sikuli** or **autoit** same you do in selenium.
In case you are trying to interact with native app alert, you do not need to switch to alert.
Just find the element on the alert as you find other elements and perform action. It is working fine for me.

Comment: it works well for alerts i know but i need solution for download dialogues.