# How to save a file by clicking on a link in python-internet explorer-windows

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, python, ie11

I am having a problem downloading a file using selenium.  I had to use selenium to hover over some menus and finally got to the last link which I need to click and reveal 30 zipped files that have a href link.  I want to click on each link and download.  What libraries do I have to make this available to me?  This is my problem:

Need to click the following links:

```
Corp_sub3_20180107.zip
corp_sub3_20180106.zip 
corp_sub3_20180105.zip
```

When hovering my mouse over the first corp_sub3, I see [this URL pop up](https://markets.midwestiso.org/MISO/getSettlementStatementFile?entity=CORP_SUB3&nodeId=key0) in windows explorer:

Upon clicking in selenium, I get a `"do you want to open or save dialog"` box at the bottom.  I'm not able to use selenium to choose the save option for some reason.  What options do I have?  I can only use internet explorer for this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Or [How to download a file using Selenium's WebDriver?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2197/how-to-download-a-file-using-seleniums-webdriver) though some of those answers are FireFox-specific

Comment: @c32hedge, I have included a work around for internet explorer here.  I hope it helps the community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  I used pyautogui to click save when the small box appears.  So first, I downloaded pyautogui in python3.  Then, I got the position of my cursor to point to the save button and captured the coordinate using

```
pos = pyautogui.position()
```

then I used

```
pyautogui.click(x=pos[0],y=pos[1]))
```

and it worked.